# Unable to fetch data from MongoDB collection using Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to fetch the record as per some filter value using MongoDB and GoLang but its returning null data. I am explaining my json record below.

```
{
    "OrderNumber" : "EQORD/20/10001060",
    "OrderStatus" : "Pending",
    "OrderType" : "Online",
    "Comments" : "",
    "DispatchPriority" : "High",
    "Customer" : {
        "CustomerID" : "5e4e2ee2a060bd3d31af431b",
        "CustomerFirstName" : "Chehan",
        "CustomerLastName" : "Kumar",
        "CustomerMobile" : "9886688726",
        "CustomerAlternateMobile" : "",
        "CustomerEmail" : "way2chethan@live.com",
        "CustomerType" : "Parent",
        "Children" : [ 
            {
                "StudentAdmissionID" : "10021920086",
                "StudnetFirstName" : "M Sri Ranga Gayathri",
                "StudentLastName" : "",
                "StudentGrade" : "PU-2/12",
                "StudentGender" : "female",
                "Language" : "SANSKRIT"
            }
        ],
        "IsShippingAddressSameAsBillingAddress" : false,
        "StoreCode" : "DKFL",
        "StoreDescription" : "Deeksha DCFL Store is a place where Parents can purchase all the school merchandise in one place at reasonable prices.",
        "StoreBranch" : "",
        "StoreType" : "Online",
        "StoreName" : "Deeksha, Yelahanka, Bengaluru",
        "StoreCustomerId" : ""
    },
    "Products" : [ 
        {
            "ID" : 1,
            "StoreCode" : "DKFL",
            "StoreName" : "Deeksha, Yelahanka, Bengaluru",
            "StoreDescription" : "Deeksha DCFL Store is a place where Parents can purchase all the school merchandise in one place at reasonable prices.",
            "StoreBranch" : "Talaghattapura",
            "AddressLine1" : "31/1, Talaghattapura",
            "AddressLine2" : "Kanakapura Road",
            "Street" : "Vajramuneeswara Temple Road",
            "Landmark" : "",
            "Latitude" : "undefined",
            "Longitude" : "undefined",
            "City" : "Bengaluru",
            "State" : "Karnataka",
            "Country" : "India",
            "Pincode" : "560062",
            "StoreType" : "Online",
            "WarehouseCode" : "",
            "Description" : "",
            "ProductName" : "Boys White & Blue Striped Half Shirt",
            "ProductCode" : "05T9YNCON",
            "ProductType" : "C",
            "Brand" : "SA",
            "VendorCode" : "",
            "SKU" : "DKFLMSHTSAM38",
            "BASESKU" : "DKFL05T9YNCON",
            "CategoryId" : "",
            "CategoryName" : "Uniform/Formal/Shirts/Male",
            "AttributeSet" : "1000000",
            "Gender" : "M",
            "BaseUnitPrice" : 452.38,
            "TaxPercentage" : 5.0,
            "HSNCode" : 6021,
            "BaseUnitOfMeasure" : "",
            "Weight" : 0.0,
            "TaxAmount" : 22.6200008392334,
            "MRP" : 475.0,
            "Weightage" : "",
            "DiscountPrice" : 475.0,
            "TotalOrderQuantity" : 4,
            "TotalProductPrice" : 1900.0,
            "TotalProductDiscountPrice" : 1900.0,
            "MinimumPrice" : 0.0,
            "CurrencyCode" : "INR",
            "MinimumBuyQty" : 1,
            "MaximumBuyQty" : 6,
            "TotalBaseUnitofMeasure" : "",
            "TotalWeight" : "",
            "Variants" : [ 
                {
                    "Name" : "Sizes",
                    "Value" : [ 
                        "38"
                    ],
                    "Code" : [ 
                        "24", 
                        "26", 
                        "28", 
                        "30", 
                        "32", 
                        "34", 
                        "36", 
                        "38", 
                        "40", 
                        "42", 
                        "44", 
                        "46", 
                        "48"
                    ],
                    "UnitofMeasure" : ""
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "Colours",
                    "Value" : [ 
                        "WHITE"
                    ],
                    "Code" : [ 
                        "M"
                    ],
                    "UnitofMeasure" : ""
                }, 
                {
                    "Name" : "Grades",
                    "Value" : [ 
                        "PU-1/11"
                    ],
                    "Code" : [ 
                        "U", 
                        "V"
                    ],
                    "UnitofMeasure" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "IsActive" : false,
    "FocusSync" : false
}
```

This is my mongoDB json format. I am explaining my code below.

```
func SalesOrderSearch(SalesOrder *models.OrderFilterData) map[string]interface{} {
    logger.Log.Println("OrderRepository SalesOrderSearch Function Begin")
    session, error := driver.Connect()
    db := session.DB(config.Configuration.Database)
    var resp map[string]interface{}
    Status := SalesOrder.Status
    AdmissionID := SalesOrder.AdmissionID
    Grade := SalesOrder.Grade
    ProductName := SalesOrder.ProductName
    Category := SalesOrder.Category
    Branch := SalesOrder.Branch
    Vendor := SalesOrder.Vendor
    fmt.Println(AdmissionID,Grade,ProductName,Branch,Category,Vendor)
    resourceManager := resources.ResourceManager{}
    if error != nil {
        resp := utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.ERROR), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.DB_SERVER_NOT_REACHABLE_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.DB_SERVER_NOT_REACHABLE_DESC))
        return resp
    } else {
        var result []interface{}
        filter := []bson.M{
            bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"OrderStatus": Status, "Customer": bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"Children":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"StudentAdmissionID":AdmissionID}}}},"Products":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"ProductName":ProductName,"CategoryName":Category }}}},
            bson.M{ "$skip" : 0 },
            bson.M{ "$limit" : 5 },

        }
        err := db.C(ORDERCOLLECTION).Pipe(filter).All(&result)
        fmt.Println(err);
        if err != nil {
            resp = utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.ERROR), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_NOTFOUND_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_NOTFOUND_DESC))
        } else {
            resp = utils.Message(resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.SUCCESS), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FOUND_CODE), resourceManager.GetProperty(constants.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FOUND_DESC))
            resp["data"] = result
        }
    }
    defer session.Close()
    return resp
}
```

Here I need to search record as per some filter condition which has given and also it should be the or condition means if all value is there then it will match record as per all value or if some values are there it will also match the record accordingly. But in my case its not fetching the record at all. Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$elemMatch` is used when matching an array to indicate that multiple criteria should all match the same element.

You are using `$elemMatch` against the `customer` field, which does not contain an array, and therefore will not match the `$elemMatch` operator.

If the field you are matching is not an array, or if you are only specifying a single field match, there is no need to use `$elemMatch`.

For example:

```
"Children":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"StudentAdmissionID":AdmissionID}
```

and

```
"Children.StudentAdminssionId":AdmissionID
```

should match the same documents.

Your match agains the `Products` array specifies 2 fields to match, so that will require `$elemMatch`

Try:

```
bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"OrderStatus": Status, "Customer.Children.StudentAdmissionID":AdmissionID,"Products":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"ProductName":ProductName,"CategoryName":Category }}}},
```